# Is there a way to redirect prints to STDERR so they go to Log::Dispatch?

Tags: perl

I am using Log::Dispatch to handle messaging to one or more outputs. In one case I've setup a daemon that logs to a file but if a third party module it uses writes to STDERR then I don't see that in my log. I would like to be able to have anything written to STDERR to be redirected to Log::Dispatch. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this module use `warn`, or does it write directly to the `STDERR` handle?

Comment: It writes directly to STDERR, i.e. `print STDERR`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could `tie` it to do whatever you want. See [`perltie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html#Tying-FileHandles):

```
{
    package StderrToLogDispatch;
    sub TIEHANDLE {
        my ($pkg) = @_;
        return bless {}, $pkg;
    }
    sub PRINT {
        my @msg = @_;
        chomp $msg[-1];
        # I don't use Log::Dispatch, so don't know if this is even close
        Log::Dispatch->logToFile(@msg);
    }
}

tie *STDERR, 'StderrToLogDispatch';
print STDERR 'foo';   # invokes StderrToLogDispatch->PRINT
```

Comment: Actually since it doesn't maintain any state, you can get away with `bless \do{0}, $pkg`